# Trouble getting CSS box-shadow to work with fixed header and footer

Tags: css

I built a website with fixed header, fixed footer, and scrolling body atop WP 4.0 "Twenty Twelve" theme.

Trying to apply boxshadow below header's gray area and above footer's gray area, but cannot get either to work. Let's focus on header. Basic HTML/CSS works, as intended, in simplified form: http://jsfiddle.net/tvq5hw4r/

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar" class="shadow-below">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
Home | About | Contact
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div><!-- #menubar -->
```

CSS:

```
#menubar {
    width:100%;
    height:1em;
    background-color: lightgray; 
    padding: .5em;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: content-box; 
}

.shadow-below {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;

/* For IE 8 */
       -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
```

Yet, I've tested actual web page in multiple browsers (FF, Chrome, IE) on multiple OSes (Vista Home Premium SP2, Android 4.4), and don't see desired result on any combo.

Have tried going through selectors connected to the gray area, id by id and class by class, assigning desired style. At most, I get dropshadow below text (but *within* gray area, rather than below it); in all other cases, I get no dropshadow whatsoever.

I have also tried taking style code from a working dropshadow on the same page (on an image) and using that verbatim on the relevant selectors: still no change.

Tried using working CSS styling from another website that I also created: no change.

Tried code suggested by other websites (css-tricks and robertnyman- can't post the full links): no change.

Tried adding "!important" to each style declaration: no change.

Since it's not a browser issue or an issue with basic code, it appears to be a problem with how styles are cascading (or how elements are nested), or maybe even with overflow or some such property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving `margin-bottom` to `.shadow-below`

EG

```
.shadow-below { margin-bottom:10px; }
```

Comment: Wow, Karan: that was fast! Thank you very much!